# SAS length statement

Tags: sas

I've just realised how useful it is to reduce the length of numeric (dummies and integers) variables, since it saves me both time and diskspace. However, I think it's convenient to use the length statement at the end of my code rather than before mentioning "set" (the latter way is how SAS bloggers and other experts mostly recommend you to use the length statement).

So, is there a difference between these two ways (see the examples below)? I can't find any differences in the output, but I'm a bit worried that I might be doing something wrong. Can you please explain what the difference is (if there is one) and why you would prefer to do it the either way.

Thanks in advance!

**This is an example of how I use the length statement:**

```
data b;  
set a;

dummy = income > 10 000;

label "dummy = Income > 10 000";

length dummy 3;

run;
```

**But here is how the experts recommend you to do it.**

```
data b;  
length dummy 3;  
set a;

dummy = income > 10 000;

label "dummy = Income > 10 000";

run;
```

Comment: Might it not be, that before the `length` statement the value of `dummy` might be assigned some huge length? And first after the `length` statement gets cropped. Resulting in heap fragmentation or so.

Comment: @JoopEggen (as I state in my answer) SAS numeric variables are always 8 bytes exactly during computation; the numeric length only affects storage space, and can never be over 8 bytes.  SAS is a 4GL and isn't anything like C or even R in terms of letting you make mistakes like that.

Comment: Reducing the length may save time in I/O (reads / writes) but would increase CPU time due to the need to convert to length 8 for PDV processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would swear that in previous versions of SAS, you'd not be able to override the length of the variable once defined by a length statement or "inherited" from source data.

I remember some notes or warnings about "length of the variable ... was already set".

In SAS 9.3 the code:

```
data a;
    length income dummy 8.;
    income = 1234567890;
    dummy = 1234567890;
    output;
    stop;
run;

data b;  
    set a;
    attrib dummy length = 3 label = "dummy = Income > 10 000";

    dummy = income > 10000;
    length dummy 8;
    length dummy 5;
run;
```

creates a variable dummy with length 5, without any notes.
So it seems to me the behaviour has changed. Previously, I'd say you would end up with a variable as defined by first of explicit definition or appearance in source data.

However it surely does not help readability and maintainability of code to first assign values to variables and define basic properties of variables at the very end.

Btw the correct definition of label would be: `label dummy = "dummy = Income > 10 000";`

Alternatively you might prefer `ATTRIB` statement to specify various properties of single variable in single statement.

```
data b;  
    set a (drop = dummy);
    attrib dummy length = 3 label = "dummy = Income > 10 000";

    dummy = income > 10000;

run;
```

Comment: Thanks vasja. I'm glad to hear that both alternatives seems to be just as correct.

And thanks for mentioning the attrib statement, I haven't heard about it before.

Answer (score 3):

Numeric variables may have their length changed at any time, while character variables may have it only done prior to their creation.  That's because a numeric variable's length only affects the output dataset; inside the PDV, numeric variables always have 8 bytes of precision regardless of any length statements.  However, character variables may not have their lengths redefined, as the PDV length associated with a character variable is not fungible after it is initially defined (in a set statement or the first length/attrib/assignment for a character variable).  See the documentation on [LENGTH](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000218807.htm) for more details (although not as many as I'd like to see).

That said, personally I prefer formatting and lengths up front rather than at the end.  Part of this is so that anyone reading the program knows going in what the ultimate formats will be; but most of it is that *some* lengths/attribs must be done up front: character lengths, in particular, and any variable where you need to specify the type (numeric/character) ahead of time in order to ensure you end up with the right type.  If you usually put lengths at the end, you'll end up with a mixture of some at front/some at end, and as such I'd rather do all at front to be more organized.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I realise now that it's probably wise to only use the length statement up front.